# Orthonormalization of non-hermitian matrix eigenvectors

Tags: syntax, matrix, linear-algebra

When using `Orthogonalize[]` one can specify which definition of "inner product" is to be used. For example, `Orthogonalize[vectors,Dot]` presupposes that all values are real.

When dealing with non-hermitian matrices, the "inner product" definition (apparently) needs to be $|z|^2 = zz$, just like with real numbers.

Consider this matrix:

```
mat = {{0. + 1.002 I, -1}, {-1, -I}}
```

The following code does not orthonormalize the eigenvectors of my matrix, as can be seen:

```
Orthogonalize[N[Eigenvectors[mat]]];
N[%[[1]].%[[2]]]

-2.90378*10^-15 + 0.999 I
```

The `Dot` option does not work, it presents me with an error

> Orthogonalize::ornfa: The second argument Dot is not an inner product function, which always should return a number or symbol. If its two numeric arguments are the same, it should return a non-negative real number.

which is not surprising, since I have complex entries.

How can I force `Orthogonalize[]` to use the real number inner product definition, without `Dot`?

*I'm using the words "inner product", but feel free to correct me as it seems they're not appropriate. Maybe I should say "involution"?*

**EDIT**

As there's a bounty on this question, I'm leaving it open until the last day it's effective. Thanks for the answers.

After talking with my supervisor, turns out we'll have to "manually" orthonormalize eigenvectors *that share the same eigenvalue*, since the eigenvectors are otherwise already orthonormal, as in this case:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Could you please be more specific? A Hamiltonian is an operator, so what does it have to do with your `list`? Or are you talking about matrices?

Comment: I fear this question may be easy to misinterpret.  Generally, an hermitian operator on a vector space is a linear operator for which $A^{\*}=A$ where $\*$ is an *involution*.  When the vector space is real, $*$ is usually the transpose.  When the space is complex, $*$ can be taken either as the transpose or the complex conjugate transpose.  This gives rise to *orthogonal* and *hermitian* operators, respectively.  I *believe* (but am not sure) that the question asks how to specify which involution is intended when undertaking certain operations (but it's not entirely clear).

Comment: F'x, a matrix merely is one way (out of many) to specify an operator.

Comment: Would this be more comprehensible?

Comment: If you are talking about the inner product for your vectors, then `zz` does not satisfy the [inner product axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space), regardless of the properties of the operator you are considering. So, the orthogonalization procedure with such inner product does not make much sense to me. Perhaps, I mis-interpreted your problem?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Well, that's the catch. I need to use a different definition of the inner product since my operator is not hermitian.

Comment: @CHM if your matrix represents a Hamiltonian, then it should be Hermitian. You probably have a problem somewhere…

Comment: You probably did not get my point: regardless of the type of an operator, `zz` is *not* an inner product, in particular because it violates axioms #1 (conjugation) and #3 (positive-definiteness) on inner products. Technically, you can still use it  to orthogonalize with it, but your vectors won't have a real length, meaning for example that you can not intepret the wave function squared as a probability density. AFAIK, the standard approach for expressing things like decays (non-unitary w.f. evolution) is to use the density matrix formalism, where at least you don't have this problem.

Comment: @F'x AFAIK, there have been studies of non-Hermitian Hamiltionians, e.g. [this one](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0703096) (I was lucky to have attended the seminar where the author explained his work). From physical viewpoint, what matters is that the spectrum is real and that probability is preserved.

Comment: @Leonid this is actually a rather active area; there was a conference recently here, http://www.mpipks-dresden.mpg.de/~phhqpx11/ (I don't work on this, just went to a few talks out of curiosity)

Comment: I've worked on this too. The main point is that the right eigenvectors of a non-hermitian operator don't usually form an orthogonal set. But using the left _and_ right eigenvectors one can define a _biorthogonal_ product which looks sort of what @CHM is indicating by _zz_ (i.e. missing the complex conjugation). These margins are too small to fit in more...

Comment: @acl Oh, I have no doubts it is active (thanks for the link b.t.w.). While I did not work on it directly, I did work with density matrix formalism when working in Quantum Optics, and also saw some references to this from the Random Matrix Theory side when working in that field much later. But that's been long time ago :)

Comment: Would `Abs[#1.#2]&` work?

Comment: @celtschk it evaluates to 1, yes.

Comment: @F'x there can be a perturbed Hamiltonian which is not anymore Hermitian.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way I am interpreting this question, it has nothing to do with the vectors in question being eigenvectors of any particular matrix. If this interpretation is wrong, the question needs to be clarified.

The next point is that orthogonality requires an *actual* scalar product, and for a complex vector space this rules out the `Dot` product because `Dot[{I,0},{I,0}] == -1` which is obviously not positive.

Therefore, the only way that it could make sense to speak of orthogonalization with respect to the `Dot` product for complex vectors is that you might wish for some reason to apply the orthogonalization *algorithm* (e.g., Gram-Schmidt) to a set of vectors with complex entries.

Doing this is completely legitimate, but it will *not* lead to vectors that are *orthogonal* with respect to the `Dot` product because the `Dot` product is *not* a scalar product. It just doesn't make sense to use the term "orthogonality" in this case.

Here is a function that performs the algorithm as described:

```
orthoDotize[vecs_] := Module[{s, a, e, ortho},
  s = Array[a, Dimensions[vecs]];
  ortho = Orthogonalize[s];
  ortho /. Thread[Flatten[s] -> Flatten[vecs]]
  ]
```

This function has the property that its output satisfies the expected Euclidean orthogonality relations when the vectors in the list `vecs` are real. If they are *not* real, then the dot product after "pseudo-orthogonalization" can have imaginary parts:

```
mat = {{0. + 1.002 I, -1}, {-1, -I}};
evecs = N[Eigenvectors[mat]];
ovecs = orthoDotize[evecs]
```

> `{{0.722734 + 0. I, -2.69948*10^-16 + 0.691127 I}, {3.67452*10^-15 + 
>      0.691127 I, 0.722734 - 3.56028*10^-15 I}}`

```
Chop[ovecs[[1]].ovecs[[2]]]
```

> `0. + 0.999001 I`

**Edit: a possible cause of confusion**

However, as I mentioned in my comment to the question (March 28), it could also be that there is a mathematical misunderstanding of a different kind here: equating orthogonality with *biorthogonality*.

As explained on [this MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvector.html), we can define left and right eigenvectors of the matrix `mat`, which in this case are transposes of each other because `mat` is symmetric. To get these (generally different) sets of eigenvectors, you can do

```
eR = Eigenvectors[mat];
eL = Transpose[Eigenvectors[Transpose[mat]]];
```

The last line follows from

$\begin{eqnarray*}\vec{x}_{L}^{\top}M & = & \lambda \vec{x}_{L}^{\top}\\\Leftrightarrow\,\,\,M^{\top}\vec{x}_{L} & = & \lambda \vec{x}_{L}\end{eqnarray*}$

Then the following holds:

```
eL.eR // Chop
```

> $\begin{pmatrix}0.0446879 & 0\\0 & 0.0446879\end{pmatrix}$

The appearance of the diagonal matrix here means that the rows of the matrix `eL` (the left eigenvectors) are orthogonal to the columns of `eR` (the right eigenvectors) in the sense of the *matrix product*. This is *automatically* true, and there is no need to do any further orthogonalization.

**Edit 2**

In case it needs further clarification: for any *symmetric* matrix `mat` we have that `Transpose[eR] == eL`. This implies that `Transpose[eR].eR` is diagonal (see above) and therefore `eR[[1]].eR[[2]] == 0`. That's why there is no need for any further orthogonalization in the example given in the question.

**Edit 3**

If `mat` is *not* symmetric, then its (right) eigenvectors are not orthogonal in the dot multiplication sense. Forming any kind of linear combination of those eigenvectors with the intention of orthogonalizing them will lead to new vectors which in general are *no longer eigenvectors* (unless the vectors in question share the same eigenvalue). So the orthogonalization idea is either *trivial* (for symmetric matrices) or *violates the eigenvector property* (for general non-symmetric matrices with non-degenerate spectrum).

Comment: Thanks for your comment on my answer Jens, I see what you mean now. I've deleted my "solution" as it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: There _is_ (or was) a mathematical misunderstanding. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 5):

You can indeed check the difference between `Orthogonalize` as it applies to real and complex vectors:

```
Orthogonalize[{{1, 1}, {1, -1}}]
Orthogonalize[{{1, 1}, {1, -1}}, Dot]
```

[image]

While if you use `Orthogonalize` on complex vectors, by default the inner produt is indeed $u.v = \sum u_i \bar{v}_i$:

```
Orthogonalize[{{1, 1}, {1, I}}]
Orthogonalize[{{1, 1}, {1, I}}, Dot[Conjugate[#1], #2] &]
Simplify@Orthogonalize[{{1, 1}, {1, I}}, Dot]
```

[image]

So, I think you can use `Dot` as second argument to `Orthodonalize` to achieve your aim. I don't know why it doesn't work for you, though…

Comment: `sevecMol = Orthogonalize[N[Eigenvectors[hamiltMol]], Dot];` returns _"The second argument Dot is not an inner product function, which always should return a number or symbol. If its two numeric arguments are the same, it should return a non-negative real number."_ I think the problem is in the `N[]` evaluation. I'm using 8.0.0.0 on OSX 10.6.8

Comment: @CHM could you give an example of `hamiltMol` (eg how you produce your hamiltonian matrix)? This is probably happening because of the form of the eigenvectors (try evaluating `Orthogonalize[N[Eigenvectors[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 3}]]], Dot]` a few times to see that it sometimes works and sometimes not).

Comment: @CHM check the output of `Dot[{0., 1. + 0.1 I}, {0., 1. + 0.1 I}]` :)

Comment: @acl I've added an image of my matrix in my question. Thanks, that surprises me. Do you know why it doesn't work all the time?

Comment: your matrix isn't hermitean so it may in general have complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors (and not all with the same phase). the dot product of two complex vectors is complex (in general).

Comment: hm...I am currently working with 49*49 non-Hermitian matrix, and I desperately try to orthogonalize the left and right eigenstates with the given above advices. I often get computation errors and have no idea how to handle it. I have also tried the Lapack routine (in Python), but it has not output me all the imagionary parts of the eigenvectors. And I cannot check this analytically. Maybe, somebody had the same problem and can give me a nice suggestion? Look forward...

Answer (score 4):

Apparently this can be made to work for exact input.

```
mat = {{1002/1000 I, -1}, {-1, -I}};
evecs = Eigenvectors[mat];

ovecs = Simplify[Orthogonalize[evecs, Dot]]

Out[122]= {{0, 
  0}, {(I*(-1001 + Sqrt[2001]))/Sqrt[-4002 + 2002*Sqrt[2001]], 
     500*Sqrt[2/(-2001 + 1001*Sqrt[2001])]}}
    mat = {{1002/1000 I, -1}, {-1, -I}};
    evecs = Eigenvectors[mat];
```

The problem is that their dot product is zero, so we cannot get a full set in this way. Stated differently, according to this "inner product" they are actually parallel.