# Orthogonalization is not commutative!

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I get stuck into a problem: I am going to produce orthogonalized eigenvectors of a matrix and in any iteration. I shortened my question in the bellow line:

Why do we face to different results of orthogonalization on vectors, and if we have to choose an orthogonalized eigenvectors to next processes, which of them is reliable? for example:

```
a={{2,4},{3,5}}
b={{3,5},{2,4}}

orthoa={{1/Sqrt[5], 2/Sqrt[5]}, {2/Sqrt[5], -(1/Sqrt[5])}}
orthob={{3/Sqrt[34], 5/Sqrt[34]}, {-(5/Sqrt[34]), 3/Sqrt[34]}}
```

Although, {3,5} is repeated in to but orthogonalized it seems to e different.

Comment: For me (Mathematica 10.2 on Mac OS), `nonorthostorage === storagematrix1`. Are you sure you've written down the outputs correctly?

Comment: @PatrickStevens, Ok I am so sorry the line is related to nonorthostorage! I corrected that.

Comment: Er, the commands to generate `nonorthostorage` and `storagematrix1` are identical.

Comment: So sorry,  i corrected the code generated the storagematrix1

Comment: (1) This really needs to be pruned to a simpler example. Also I don't see an actual question. My guess is you are orthogonalizing the same set of vectors but given in different orders, and want to know if the results can/should be different. If that's the issue, then the answer is yes, they can and should be different.

Comment: I simplified it a bit - it's waiting for peer review - but my answer below contains the simplest possible example.

Comment: (2) Also theres is the issue of what the result might mean. Once you orthogonalize the set of vectors, they are no longer in general eigenvectors. That only works for orthogonalizing subsets of eigenvectors that belong to the same eigenvalue.

Comment: @mr.0093  What you are saying, assuming you are the poster of this question, is that you made zero effort to track down the source of the apparent issue. Why would you think others would want to isolate it if it's not important enough for you to do so?

Comment: @Daniel, No, It is a big misunderstanding, I just said I did not know where is the problem. I had said if I write all things, maybe it helps to others to see all I see. I did not know if I just write a small list, I can tell all of which I wrote. It took me a long time for writing the question rather than a short one!!!

Comment: Also, I wrote a comment in bellow related to @mr.0093. which is not important to repeat.

Comment: The response from @PatrickStevens has isolated an example (as I wish had been done in the original post). And it has explained the issue under discussion. If this is not the case then you will need to rewrite the question to make it clear.

Comment: Possibly related (perhaps similar misunderstanding): [Orthonormalization of non-hermitian matrix eigenvectors](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3649/245)

Comment: @Jens, I think It is so helpful. However I can't understand what the original resources of my problem. but your link contains important notes.

Comment: I am so sorry, if @mr.0093 (my roommate)answered instead me, since he did not have any answer to me, collaborated to write question for following it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call `Orthogonalize` at the end, you're orthogonalizing the eigenvectors in a different order (i.e. after sorting on eigenvalue, rather than before). Orthogonalizing the same list in a different order usually gives a different output.

```
Orthogonalize[{{1., 2}, {1, 3}}]

(* {{0.447214, 0.894427}, {-0.894427, 0.447214}} *)

Orthogonalize[{{1, 3}, {1., 2}}]

(* {{0.316228, 0.948683}, {0.948683, -0.316228}} *)
```

Comment: If the orthogonalized eigenvectors are needed to the next process which of them are dependable?

Comment: The output of `Orthogonalize[m]` is a collection of orthonormal vectors. They are not in general eigenvectors of `m` unless there is only one eigenvalue (example: `{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}`).

Comment: If mr.0093 is the same person as Ackaran, there is a merging procedure: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: No this is my roommate. he said he didn't have so knowledge to answer me.

Comment: I am so sorry, if @mr.0093 (my roommate)answered instead me, since he did not have any answer to me, collaborated to write question for following it.