# Orthogonalization and normalization during eigendecomposition

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I have the following simple code to compute the eigenspectrum of a complex symmetric matrix `A`, and its column of eigenvectors `Q`:

```
A = {{1.0 + I, I, 0}, {I, I, I}, {0, I, I}};
eig = Eigensystem[A];
Q = Transpose[eig[[2]]]; (*column of eigenvectors, s.t. Q^-1AQ = 1*)
```

Let us consider two operations. Firstly

```
Transpose[Q].Q // MatrixForm // Chop
```

gives `0` along the *off-diagonals* but non-zero numbers along the *diagonals*; and

```
Transpose[Q].Conjugate[Q] // MatrixForm // Chop
```

gives `1` along the *diagonals* and non-zero numbers along the *off-diagonals*.

This means that every eigenvector is normalized using its complex conjugate version (as the second operation shows) but orthogonalized with respect to every other eigenvector **without** any complex conjugation (as the first operation shows).

Any idea why such a (strange) convention is chosen? I would have expected the first operation to simply give the identity matrix, which is a common convention.

Comment: What do you mean here by "convention"? I think is just the way things are. Dwell on the result of this: `eig2 = Eigensystem@Transpose@A; Q2 = Transpose[eig2[[2]]]; Transpose[Q2].Q // Chop`.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [Orthonormalization of non-hermitian matrix eigenvectors](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3649/245)

Comment: `A` is not Hermitian...

Comment: @Daniel, the OP did say "complex symmetric" in the first sentence; so, definitely not Hermitian.

Comment: @Jens that is indeed useful; so you are saying that *biorthogonality* is used for the left and right eigenvectors; whereas for a *given* eigenvector, the scalar product (with complex conjugation) is used. However if I use `Orthogonalize` on the eigenvectors after `Eigensystem` is invoked, then it gives back eigenvectors where the scalar product (with complex conjugation) is used both for normalization and orthogonalization. I guess my question was: why doesn't Mathematica do this in the first place?

Comment: You cannot use `Orthogonalize` on the eigenvectors of a general matrix unless the eigenvalues are degenerate. Otherwise you're mixing eigenvectors to different eigenvalues in the orthogonalization,  and end up with results that aren't eigenvectors at all. The eigenvalues of your `A` are indeed non-degenerate.

Comment: @Jens Thms. 7.7 and 7.8 from [Matrix and Linear Algebra](https://books.google.it/books?id=ukyjDQAAQBAJ) state that the  biorthogonality condition for a complex matrix $A$ is $Q^{\dagger} P = 1$, where $Q$ ($P$) is constructed from its left (right) eigenvectors as columns. For $A = A^{T}$ we indeed obtain the orthogonality condition between eigenvectors $x_i$ and $x_j$ without the conjugate, as my example and the one in your linked question (correctly) showed; moreover per the above theorems this should also be true when $i = j$. However in both examples for $i=j$ the conjugate is required.

Comment: Everything is consistent: *Mathematica* sees a numerical matrix which has non-degenerate eigenvectors. There is no freedom of choice other than to multiply each by an arbitrary complex number so as to enforce *normalization*, which has nothing to do with the question of orthogonality or biorthogonality in that case. For normalization, it uses the unitary scalar product appropriate for a complex vector space, and that's what you're seeing. It just so happens that the eigenvectors in this case are *not* orthogonal under that scalar product, and cannot be made orthogonal either.